# How to copy members from one security group to another security group in AD using PowerShell v4?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I'm relatively new to PowerShell and am trying to learn it for a project at work involving Active Directory. The task I have is to compare the members of two different security groups in AD (both groups are located in the same OU) and copy the members from Group 2 that are not in Group 1 over to Group 1.

I came across [this link](http://ravingroo.com/1030/powershell-compare-membership-of-two-active-directory-groups/) that showed how to compare groups but:

1. The code segment listed on this website returns both the members from Group 1 that aren't in Group 2 and the members from Group 2 that aren't in Group 1 which is way more information than I need
2. Once I get the list I don't know how to use that to enter into a command or script to copy those members to the appropriate group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Try the below script which I have written for your requirement.

```
#Input Parameters. Change these as per your requirement
$group1 = "Group1Name"
$group2 = "Group2Name"

$membersInGroup1 = Get-ADGroupMember $group1
$membersInGroup2 = Get-ADGroupMember $group2

if($membersInGroup1 -eq $null)
{
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1 -Members $membersInGroup2
}
elseif($membersInGroup2 -ne $null)
{
  $separateMembers = diff $membersInGroup1 $membersInGroup2

  if($separateMembers -ne $null)
  {
    foreach($member in $separateMembers)
    {
      $currentUserToAdd = Get-ADUser -Identity $member.InputObject
      Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1 -Members $currentUserToAdd
      }
  }
}
```

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: As you are new, if this resolves your issue, please accept this as answer by clicking on the tick mark under the arrows, beside my answer.

Comment: Thanks for  the help. The script worked perfectly. I don't know if I totally understand how part of the script worked, but I'm sure in time with working with PowerShell, it will make more sense eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution which is very easy that I could not resist to share with you all:

`Get-ADGroupMember -Identity GROUP-A | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf GROUP-B`

`Get-ADGroupMember` gets all the members of GROUP-A and pipes into [`Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`](https://anandthearchitect.com/2011/04/12/active-directory-copy-a-group-members-to-a-new-group/) cmdlet that added the incoming members to GROUP-B.

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617203.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Given two security groups, DestinationGroup (Group 1), SourceGroup (Group 2):

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "DistinguishedName of DestinationGroup" -Members (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "DistinguishedName of SourceGroup" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty distinguishedName)
```